# Order basket, does not choose the delivery method, magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

When we are in the basket, and we have filled in all the data and we want to choose the delivery method, then when we click on it, it will be selected and immediately reset, and then it will have to be pressed again a couple of times. What could be such a bug? Why he resets several times the selected delivery method. And this happens only when we first go to the cart, then from the first time, it chooses the delivery method.